# Переформулировать фразу для заблокированного сообщения

Tags: предложение, локализация, заблокированные-сообщения

У заблокированного вопроса показывается такая плашка:

> **Заблокирован на 10 часов.** Комментарии для этого вопроса отключены, но, тем не менее, публикация ответов и другие действия для него доступны. Подробнее.

[image: скриншот плашки]

Хотя на самом деле заблокирован он неделю назад сроком на неделю:

[image: скриншот истории]

Т. е. 10 часов - это время до истечения бокировки, а не время, на которое вопрос заблокирован.

Думаю, надо как-то переформулировать.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, почему [meta-tag:предложение]?

Comment: Так [вот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11887/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/11888?noredirect=1#comment51202_11888) же.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ну так это ж пример. А надо обсудить варианты.

Comment: Можно и [meta-tag:обсуждение] вернуть, но [meta-tag:предложение] всё равно надо, так как речь об изменении существующего состояния.

Answer (score -1):

Не вижу особого смысла тут что-то менять. В каждый текущий момент плашка отображает время, на которое вопрос (ещё) будет считаться заблокированным.

В английском варианте, [например](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70954789/3240681), выглядит так:

> [image: Locked for]

Информации о том, насколько вопрос был заблокирован изначально в данном контексте нет, да и не нужна она, будет только вводить в заблуждение.

Плюс, я не сторонник добавлять в переводы какого-то нового смысла, которого не было в оригинальной строке. [Строка выглядит так](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13534):

> Locked for $timeLeft$

Comment: Так я предлагаю менять формулировку, а не время добавлять. Например, `Заблокирован ещё $timeLeft$` или что-то такое.

Comment: @Qwertiy зачем?

Comment: Чтобы звучало однозначно.

Comment: @Qwertiy так и сейчас всё понятно. Думаешь, кто-то будет ожидать разблокировки раньше, чем написано на плашке?

Comment: @Qwertiy, что-то вроде "Сообщение заблокировано, до конца блокировки $timeLeft$"